# Is the phrase "for us to put the books on" an adjectival or adverbial phrase?

Tags: grammar, adverbials, adjectival-phrases

I'm wondering whether the boldfaced phrase is adjectival or adverbial:

> John cleared the desk **for us to put the books on**.

Comment: It's a purpose infinitive clause. You can call it adjectival or adverbial if you can give a good definition of both of them.

Comment: In _a bookcase for us to put the books on_ it would be clearly adjectival in function. Here it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Adverbials answer questions that provide context in a sentence (e.g. why, when, where, how, etc.), whereas adjectivals describe participants (nouns and pronouns) in a sentence.

Hence, adverbials can often be moved or even omitted without altering the fundamental meaning of the sentence. This property applies to the clause in bold here: *John cleared the desk.*

The main purpose of the clause in bold is to provide context, i.e. the reason why John cleared the desk. In other words, it's adverbial.

[What’s the Difference Between Adverbial and Adjectival?](https://lemongrad.com/adverbial-vs-adjectival/)

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean "For us to put the books on, John cleared the desk" is okay?

Comment: @Apollyon Not unless your name is Yoda :) Adverbials can often be moved, but not always.

Comment: In this sense, the boldfaced phrase is like an adjectival. Adjectivals modifying a noun often cannot be detached from it. Also, the final preposition "to" needs to attach to a noun, like the preposition in the adjectival of "the chopsticks for us to eat rice with."

Comment: You can put some *for* clauses at the start, but it's odd when it relates so strongly to the object of the sentence. More usual if it relates to the subject/verb. "For us to win the game, we need to try harder."